# Does the Facebook Chat API support image (photo) attachments?

Tags: facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

I'm looking at potentially integrating my IM app with the Facebook Chat API. From the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/), it's not clear whether I can send and receive image/photo attachments. It looks like it wasn't doable as of a year ago ([Sending photo in Facebook chat](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13873691/sending-photo-in-facebook-chat)), but I'm hoping something has changed? Specifically:

(1) Can I use the Facebook Chat API to retrieve photos attached to incoming messages?

(2) Can I attach a photo to an outgoing message?

Thanks!